# How to enable SSL in sonarqube

Tags: ssl, iis, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I installed Sonarqube on a server and given a domain name like http://sonarqube.xyz.com:9000 and now I would like to have the URL to be https.

I have changed the properties of sonar.properties in the conf file and tried redirecting the URL using IIS with URL rewrite.

Comment: What version of SonarQube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I followed the following blog to enable SSL with reverse proxy using IIS rewrite.

https://jessehouwing.net/sonarqube-configure-ssl-on-windows/

Thanks all for the answers

Comment: the most important part is Make sure to turn off the checkbox “Reverse rewrite host in response headers” within the ARR (Application Request Routing) configuration of IIS. (Application Request Routing Cache --> Server Proxy Settings), if you are using rewrite sonarqube server in localhost:9000

Comment: does this mean the sonar will be accessible over https rather than http over internet after applying all the steps ?

Comment: if you want to make your sonarqube accessible over internet, you need a public ip which will point to your machine and to have ssl for the sonarqube website, you need to follow the above process.

Answer (score 7):

You should follow the guidelines described at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Securing+the+Server+Behind+a+Proxy.

Comment: URL not reachable